# Java - How to find the interfaces extended by a particular interface or the super interface name

Tags: java, reflection, interface, extends

Need some help...

I need to find out the interfaces extended by a particular interface or (Super

Interface Name)

Say, I have three interfaces I1, I2, I3. I1 extends I2 and I3. A Class, MyClass extends I1.

Using Reflections in Java, I could get I1 but how to get the interfaces extended by I1 i.e. I2 and I3.

Please send some code to find out the super interface name. i.e. I2 and I3

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same that - as I assume - you're already doing for your class:

```
I1.class.getInterfaces();
```

From the JavaDoc:

> If this object represents an interface, the array contains objects representing all interfaces extended by the interface.

Just note that this would be the *directly* extended interfaces, so if I1 extends I2 and I2 extends I3, then you'd have to call that method multiple times.

Comment: Are you telling something like `interfaces[i].getClass().getInterfaces());` where interfaces[i] contains the fully qualified interface name. The output for this is `[Ljava.lang.Class;@1dd0eb0b`. Is this what you suggested or i got you wrong.

Comment: @ProttoyBagchi depends on what you are doing with that (you didn't specify that). Here are a few things: 1. `interfaces[i]` is _not_ the fully qualified name but the class object representing that interface in the JVM. 2. If you call `System.out.prinltn( interfaces[i].getClass().getInterfaces() )` you'd get the output like you described, since that will call the array's `toString()` method. If you're just printing, then try `Arrays.toString( ... )` instead.